# C++ MSVCP120D.DLL is missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2013 and I build my project under release. However when I try to execute it on another machine without visual studio but with vc_redist installed, I get the error: `msvcp120d.dll is missing from the computer`, which is used when a project is compiled in debug. Any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed both `vcredist_x86` and `cvredist_x64` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change settings in Project properties

> Right click on your project > Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation

and inside you have to change Runtime Library from Multi threader DLL (/MD) to Multi Threader (/MT). This way you won't need to include additional libraries with your build.

Answer (score 0):

First check that all your projects are actually set to build in Release.

You do this by opening the 'Configuration Manager' from Build -> Configuration Manager...

Select Release and Win32/x64 whatever you are building and then ensure all your projects are set to Release configuration.

If they are all fine then you will need to either manually check the Project settings for each project, or you can use an application such as Depends to help find the offending EXE or DLL.

http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: I checked my project and it is set to build in release. I used depends and I can only see msvcp120.dll in there, not msvcp120d.dll.